# Adding with Window Functions, from specific value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am struggling with a (Py)Spark problem.

I have a column "col" in an ordered dataframe and need a way of adding up the elements from 0. What I need is the column "sum_from_0".
I tried it with window functions but did not succeed.
Any idea on how to solve this task would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
col sum_from_0
0   None
0   None
1   1
2   3
1   4
4   8
3   11
0   None
0   None
0   None
1   1
2   3
3   6
3   9
2   11
0   None
0   None
```

Comment: try do a groupBy followed by a sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ordering column, so I made it first and add some temp columns to separate sum groups. After that, sum over the `group` partition and order by `id` window such as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w1 = Window.orderBy("id")
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("id")

df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withColumn("zero", (col("col") === 0).cast("int"))
  .withColumn("group", sum("zero").over(w1))
  .withColumn("sum_from_0", sum("col").over(w2))
  .orderBy("id")
  .drop("id", "group", "zero")
  .show(20, false)
```

that gives the results:

```
+---+----------+
|col|sum_from_0|
+---+----------+
|0  |0         |
|0  |0         |
|1  |1         |
|2  |3         |
|1  |4         |
|4  |8         |
|3  |11        |
|0  |0         |
|0  |0         |
|0  |0         |
|1  |1         |
|2  |3         |
|3  |6         |
|3  |9         |
|2  |11        |
|0  |0         |
|0  |0         |
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but this does not solve the task.

Comment: should I re-sum when I meet the `0` value?

Comment: Yes, after the value 0 it should start again.

Comment: Thank you very much!